# Header image zoom issues in Mobile Safari?

Tags: discussion, design

I see a strange phenomenon when I visit this site on my iPhone (1st gen) and zoom in and out: the header image looks different depending on the zoom level. Does anyone else have this issue?

I don't think it is a bug in the site design, but I'm curious what can cause it.

[image: Fully zoomed out, Embossed]
[image: Zoomed in, Embossed with stripes]
[image: Zoomed in, Striped]
[image: Fully zoomed in, Normal]

Comment: I'm using iPhone4 with the latest iOS. I can reproduce this somewhat, but not all of your screenshots. It looks like the browser stopped smoothing the image after zooming. I'll investigate some further. btw, your carrier's logo is killer! what is it?

Comment: @Jin: You don't have to fix this, it was just interesting and I wanted to know whether I was the only one seeing it. It could be a question for the Apple SE or Stack Overflow. My carrier is [Mobile Vikings](https://mobilevikings.com/en/), a virtual operator in Belgium that focuses on mobile internet (which is very expensive otherwise).

Comment: To piggyback off of that, on the native Android browser, I don't see the header at all, or the new fonts and colors. Looks like you're still serving the old design to Android? or is that just a limitation of the browser? I'm not complaining, just curious as to what's happening...

Comment: @goldenapples: Since a few days [all mobile browsers get a "slimmed down, minimalistic" CSS theme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so/50689#50689). So it's not limited to this site or to your browser.